# Whenever you add an item to the cart it resizes the entire header

Tags: cart, grid, css, menu, header

When you add an item to the cart it changes the header from full width and only having a blue menu bar to being a box completely blue. It fixes the problem when you remove the item from the cart.

Images to how what I mean

without items - https://i.stack.imgur.com/93hhQ.png
with items - https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAvyI.jpg

the link to the site is image-displays.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to place following tag after the closing of div in header which has "span12" class

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: What file/where would the tag be?

Comment: edit just tried it on header.phtml and i didnt work.
Place div clear after <div class="span12"> ?

Comment: It is according to the theme structure of your website. But it should be in app/design/frontend/package_name/theme_name/template/page/html/header.phtml file.

Comment: if i close the clear div on the same line it doesnt do anything. If I close it after it gets rid of an entire section of the header.

Comment: It is working if we place clear div after <div class="span12"> -- </div> 
Ref: http://awesomescreenshot.com/00d30xwk12